# Angular.js - In controller wait until service returns value from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, scope, rootscope

In my **Angular.js** application I'm stucked with such problem. I have service which is called `user` and I call it on `app.run` to get user data from server like so:

```
app.run(function (user, tracking) {
    user.initialize();
    ... // some other code goes here..
});
```

This simply calls API route and creates `$rootScope.user` to be available through all application.

But somehow controller from time to time loads faster then initializing goes.. and `$rootScope` inside it doesn't contain `user` object.

```
function SomeController($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
   console.log($rootScope.user.name); 
   // sometimes returns error -
   // TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
}
```

So how can I force all controllers load only after initializing to `$rootScope` went well. I don't want to add `$watch` on user in every controller.. 'cause it looks like bad decision and makes code ugly.

Your suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Do you use `ngRoute`? Bcoz there's `resolve` on it that you can use for it.

Comment: @IqbalFauzi yes, I use ``ngRoute``. Does it mean I need call ``user.initialize()`` inside ``resolve`` on every controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is to use `resolve` option of `$routeProvider.when()` method.

This will prevent controller to load before request to data is finished:

```
$routeProvider.when('/books', { 
  templateUrl: 'books', 
  controller: 'bookCtrl',
  resolve: {
    appUser: function (user) {
       // we're injecting "user" service
       // and initiliazing it (this method returns $promise)
       return user.initialize();
    }
  }  
});
```

And inside `bookCtrl` just injecting `appUser` as a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The only solution I found was to create some function in the rootScope and call it from the controller. So the app.run function has inside something like that:

```
scope.initUser = function () {
   if (!user){
   // create
      user.initialize();
   }
};
```

And then my controller call it at the beginning:

```
$rootScope.initUser();
```

Don't forget to inject the $rootScope into the controller.

This solution doesn't pretend to be elegant but at least it works...

I would appreciate if someone suggest better solution...